# kubernetes CI/CD: automate docker build, tag and push tasks on a CI/CD infrastructure

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, openshift

We're setting a CI/CD infrastructure in order to deploy our applications on openshift/kubernetes.

We're deploying applications using `jenkins`, `fabric8` and `helm`.

Nevertheless, we're creating some other kind of artifacts: `init` and `sidecar` images. So, our applications need that those images are available on kubernetes/openshift registry before main containers start.

Currently, we're `building`, `tagging` and `pushing` them on openshift/kubernetes registry, manually.

```
$ docker build .
$ docker tag image <registry>/image
$ docker push <registry>/image
```

We want to automate this process, I mean, we'd really like to avoid performing these three steps and we want to avoid to configure a docker client on a jenkins slave in order to push them.

I don't know if I've explained so well.

Comment: "Starting with Pipeline versions 2.5 and higher, Pipeline has built-in support for interacting with Docker from within a Jenkinsfile." https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ Or is it having to configure credentials in order to push that you're worried about? Apologies if I've not understood your concern.

Comment: I'm also not seeing what exactly is different about the sidecar and init images as opposed to your other images. I use Jenkins-X so it might be prejudicing my view of this. Are you using the OpenShift Jenkins plugin or is your Jenkins not talking with OpenShift?

Answer (score 0):

Well you would need a seperate machine installed with docker that is used just to build and push your docker image, with a software that is triggered by jenkins to do the task. But I don't know about any software doing that.

Our solution was to install docker on a jenkins node. The build itself is written as pipeline and is commited to our scm as Jenkinsfile with the steps being:

- build/test app
- build docker image
- push docker image
- delete image on jenkins node
- deploy

If you dont want to use docker on jenkins and you use java something like [jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib) could do the trick. But I'm not sure anything like that exists for other languages.

**Update:**

Thanks to Grahams suggestion you could also checkout:

- [buildah](https://github.com/projectatomic/buildah)
- [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo)

Comment: You don't strictly need docker, which can be a problem because of the need to run a daemon. You could use buildah and skopeo and not need docker at all. These tools don't require a daemon like docker does.